# NextJS 9 - Compression best practice

Tags: next.js

With the new option to use the in-built api (/pages/api) what is the new best practice way to implement gzipping on client-side js?

I've only recently started converting my app into NextJS so i'm still learning but i noticed in my lighthouse report half way through converting everything that NextJS wasn't gzipping anything in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider deploying your next.js application using [now](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/deploying-a-nextjs-app).

It handles the compression transparently at the network/hosting layer and it's quite decent. 
The setup is simple. Check it out here https://zeit.co/docs/v2/network/compression.

Best of all, it's free.

I'm using it on my [website](https://www.lavax.co/) as well and I have got a quite decent score in lighthouse speed test.

Comment: @xun, what if export the project and host it as static files, do you have any idea what should be done in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer my own question in a non-ideal way to fix this in my project as a band-aid approach was to create a server.js file in the root directory (custom server approach) and paste this....

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = "production";
const compression = require("compression");
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express();
    if (!dev) {
        server.use(compression());
    }
    server.all("*", (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res)
    });
    server.listen(port, err => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
    })
});
```

And change the npm start command to this....

```
"start": "node server.js"
```

this handles all requests (get/post/delete etc) with the NextJS custom server handler but with compression attached always.